# Dropdown selection in Cypress

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, cypress, dropdown

I need to locate this dropdown element and click on it. I have done below. But it does not work. What am doing wrong?

```
const pageObjects = new PageObjects();
 const brandOfTheCar = "Renau";
 pageObjects.getSelectAbrandBtn().type(brandOfTheCar);
 cy.get(".brand-filter__control")
    .find("div div")
    .contains("Renault")
    .click()
    .click({ multiple: true, force: true });
  pageObjects.getApplyFiltersBtn().click();
});[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Please let me know when you click on the dropdown and class appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you use contains with `div` and the inner text value `Renault (3)`.

```js
cy.contains('div', 'Renault (3)').click()
```

Comment: But at this moment it is (3) next time might be another number? Need to be something dynamic

Comment: You can add just the text part as well `cy.contains('div', 'Renault').click()` if that works

Comment: nope it did not work, I attached the result as screen shot to the post

Comment: Don't use get and find command. Directly use `cy.contains('div', 'Renault').click()`.

Comment: another error occured. SC is attached

Comment: cy.click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM. @Alapan Das

Comment: Please remove the second click.

Comment: yeap my fault..